# Github action: docker/build-push-action@v2 set network=host

Tags: docker, github-actions

We use to build our projects using Github Actions and Docker. As you can imagine, on each push of our dev teams, a well-defined pipeline take the changes, build the new image and push it into the registry. In a couple of days the pipeline start to throw "bizarre" errors about connection issues. Just re-run the whole pipeline fixes it temporarily. Today, the pipeline has reached the point of no return. Every build got stucked on the same docker build step:

```
RUN apt/apk/yum update
```

...and the output is something like that:

[image: Github action screenshot]

Now, I managed to find the solution to this problem in this [github issue thread](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/307). As suggested to several users, I tried to run `docker build -t <image_name> --network=host .` on a simple Dockerfile (which contains an alpine image running `apk update` command).

Everything works like a charm. Now I have to apply this fix to the github action pipeline.

First of all, let's take a look to the docker build phase, defined into the pipeline (for security reasons, I masked some part of the Dockfile):

```
  - name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      push: true
      file: Dockerfile
      tags: |
        <image>
      build-args: |
        <args>
      cache-from: type=registry,ref=<image_cache>
      cache-to: type=registry,ref=<image_cache>
```

Looking to the official documentation of [docker/build-push-action@v2](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#customizing), we are allowed to define the network configuration during the build, simply adding

```
network: host
```

in `with:` customizations.

Following the [official documentation of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---network), regarding network param, quote:

> The use of --network=host is protected by the network.host
> entitlement, which needs to be enabled when starting the buildkitd
> daemon with --allow-insecure-entitlement network.host flag or in
> buildkitd config, and for a build request with --allow network.host
> flag.

So, combining both the documentation, I thought the right way to define the network param is something like that:

```
  - name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      push: true
      allow: network.host,security.insecure #NEW
      network: host #NEW
      file: Dockerfile
      tags: |
        <image>
      build-args: |
        <args>
      cache-from: type=registry,ref=<image_cache>
      cache-to: type=registry,ref=<image_cache>
```

but it doesn't work. Same situation, stucked on apk/apt upgrade for ages.

So I'm here to ask to you how to correctly configure docker/build-push-action@v2 stage in order to define the param `network=host` and overcome the connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
        with:
          driver-opts: |
            network=host
```

Comment: Correct, but you have also to specify into the docker/build-push-action@v2 step the network (in this case, host) and also you have to allow the usage. Check the answer based on your one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @user19972112 solution, I figured out how to overcome this issue.

Into the `docker/setup-buildx-action@v1` step, I added two properties:

```
      buildkitd-flags: '--allow-insecure-entitlement network.host'
      driver-opts: network=host
```

Then, into docker/build-push-action@v2 step, you have to allow and specify network equal to host:

```
      allow: network.host
      network: host
```

So, the result will be:

```
[...]

 - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    id: buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
    with:
      version: latest
      endpoint: builders
      buildkitd-flags: '--allow-insecure-entitlement network.host'
      driver-opts: network=host
 
[...]

 - name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      push: true
      allow: network.host
      network: host
      file: ./docker/.dockerfile
[...]
```